# How to export all e-mail addresses from Exchange 2003?

Tags: active-directory, email, exchange-2003

I'm trying to gather a list of *all e-mail addresses* being used by our Exchange 2003 system, which includes not only the normal user addresses, but *distribution groups* and *aliases* as well.  I also need the output formatted like: *user@domain.com* - although, we only have one domain, so even if I can get the *user* part, that would work.

I don't care about account-association here, I really just need a list of addresses.

**How can I go about doing an export of all smtp e-mail addresses from Exchange 2003, including distribution group and alias addresses in the *user@domain.com* format?**

I would prefer something that can be accomplished via the command line so that it can be generated by a script, but it would be just as useful if there is a way to do this manually (read: point and click) as well.

Any ideas?  I don't see anything within System Manager that can do this, and my searching isn't turning up anything that can fulfill all the above requirements.

**Solved**

This is how I'm using the accepted answer:

```
@echo off

ldifde -f c:\temp\ldifde-dump.txt -l proxyaddresses
find "@" < c:\temp\ldifde-dump.txt > c:\temp\email-addresses.txt
del c:\temp\ldifde-dump.txt
```

This produces c:\temp\email-addresses.txt, which, although it contains a little extra garbage characters, it can easily be parsed out with a search & replace in Notepad++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need primary email addresses, you can run this on your Exchange server, filling in the domain and com values:

```
csvde -r "(mail=*)" -d "dc=domain,dc=com" -l mail -f c:\gal.csv
```

To get secondary email addresses, its a bit trickier. You can use this to generate a file:

```
ldifde -f dump.ldf -l proxyaddresses
```

Found a method to extract the email addresses from the LDF file here: http://bytes.com/topic/unix/answers/648158-extract-email-addresses-big-file

If you have access to perl within Windows, make a perl file that contains this:

```
while (<STDIN>) { 
while (/[\w\.\-]+@[\w\.\-]+\w+/g) 
    {print "$&\n"}}
```

Then run this command:

```
perl ExtractEmail.pl <dump.ldf >out.txt
```

Out.txt should contain all your email addresses.

Comment: Hrm, Perl is a no-go - server is on the DMZ, but the ldifde command helps a lot.  Thanks.

Comment: For those with grep but no perl you can always do something like `grep -oP "[\w\._-]+@[\w_]+\.[\w]{2,5}" dump.ldf > emails.txt`.  Obviously the regex could be expanded as needed, but that fit for my org's relatively straightforward addressing scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Adfind.exe with this:
AdFind.exe -default -nodn -nolabel -noctl proxyAddressess

Chop out all of the SMTP: or smtp: addresses.

http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/index.htm